# Restore a file overwritten with ln -nfs?

Tags: linux, debian, data-recovery, symbolic-link, file-recovery

I accidentally "deleted" a file by doing this:

```
ln -nfs /path/to/file
```

In my understanding the data itself should still be there. I also stopped working on the machine as I did this...

Is it somehow possible to get my file back by commandline operations?

Comment: Issuing this call on a file just gives me a warning since the second file name is missing. Are you sure this command actually did something (bad)?

Comment: So you're saying that you were in a directory other than `/path/to`, but that directory also contained a file called `file`, and so the `ln` command deleted your file called `file`, replacing it with a symbolic link (called `file`) to `/path/to/file`? Why do you believe that "the data itself should still be there"?

Answer (score 0):

if you check out `man ln` it shows the command you entered as

`ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)`

and states:

```
In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.
```

I tested that command out with a test file and it appeared to just create a link in the directory i was in currently, to the file i targeted, if you were in the same directory ln should have returned the error

```
ln: `testfile' and `./testfile' are the same file
```